# is there any way to prevent counter from restarting

Tags: reactjs, countdown

I'm trying to build a counter with two button start and stop, everything works great but when i want to add a function to change state on the (onClick) the counter restart every time the state changes.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnwYc.png)
[image]

Comment: Do not put screenshots of the code. Put the code itself here and even better put the jsfiddle link here as well. So other people with the same problem can find it more easily (google will not do OCR on your code and put it into their search index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because rerenders `<Countdown />` component every time `setState` happens. To fix this

```
const date = React.useMemo(()=> {return (Date.now() + 1200000)}, []);
...
<CountDown
...
data={date}
...
/>
```